# What is the concept of Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva

Lord Shiva is called the destroyer. Destroyer in what sense?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. The question in it's current form is too vague and contextual. Meanwhile I'm voting to close it.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please answer it if the question seems OK.

Comment: Destroyer of everything form Physical entities to abstract entities. He destroys ignorance, greed and evil of his devotees. As a preceptor of Yoga, he destroys Maya that shrouded us. As to obey law of nature, at appropriate times He destroys physically earth and Universe. **Shiva is Tasmic outside and Sattvik inside** and this is the reason why he gives boons to devotees easily. Vishnu is Satvik outside and Tasmic inside. Brahma is always Rajas. Same is their Shaktis too.

Comment: Lord Vishnu is ultimate destroyer, sustainer and Creator of all. Brahma is Rajasic and through the mode of Brahma and as Antaryami of brahma Lord Vishnu makes Brahma to create. Siva is absolute Tamasic and Vishnu as antaryami of Siva i.e. vehicle or mode for antaryami Vishnu who makes him to destroy. Vishnu is his own antaryami is Absolute (suddha sattva) Sattva oriented and hence performs the sustenance, i.e. and in real sense sustenance means freedom from birth and death, i.e. moksha and Vishnu is the only one who provides moksha. Similarly, are their respective shaktis.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC: Thank you for editing the question. It looks okay to me now. I have nominated for a reopening.

Comment: Lord Shiva is the destroyer of Ignorance. This ignorance is the cause of rebirth. When ignorance ends, the rebirth also ends. He puts an end to all of creation. Because all of creation is a result of Avidhya/Maya. In other words, He slays Avidhya and He grants Moksha. Thus He is called the destroyer. This is the Advaita Viewpoint. All the best!

Comment: Same question was asked already [Why Lord Shiva is considered as the destroyer of world?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9437/3500)